# StructureMap error when use with MVC in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependencies, structuremap, principles

When I install [StructureMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap-MVC3) for my project and use:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapper<UserModel, UserDto> _mapper;

        public IndexController(IMapper<UserModel, UserDto> mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<UserDto> userDb = UserDb.GetAll();
            UserModel userModel = _mapper.Map(userDb[0]);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

After run with an server error message:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>            Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>       ...

But I don't know much about the principle of dependency inversion. Please help me to resolve this.

This is `ObjectFactory` :

```
public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {
                            x.Scan(scan =>
                                    {
                                        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                    });
            //                x.For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
                        });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do next?

Comment: Have you followed the installation instruction: https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap-MVC3? Please also post your `ObjectFactory` configuration!

Comment: I have followed what you say but this error still exist. What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell StructureMap how to wire up all types that don't follow the default convention (which you use in your scan). The default convention is to wire up all interfaces to concrete implementations with the same name as the interface (minus the "I" prefix).

In your case you need to tell StructureMap to wire up all needed closed generic types of `IMapper` using:

```
x.For(typeof(IMapper<,>)).Use(typeof(MyConcreteMapper<,>);
```

Put the line above where you currently have the `x.For<IExample>().Use<Example()`.